# Mongoose find() is returning undefined docs when I send more then one request

Tags: mongoose

When I send more then one request from my web app I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

but if I use only one request so it works well. Any help?

This is my code:

```
MyModel.find(query_specifiers, function(err, docs) { 
  for (let i = 0; i < docs.length; ++i) {
  ...
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Did you specify `docs` prior to your function? If so, your scope might be garbled.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue I needed to add **poolSize** and **keepAlive**, and remove **mongoose.connection.close()** from inside the **mongoose.connect()**.

```
mongoose.connect(URL, { keepAlive: true, useNewUrlParser: true, poolSize: 10 }, function (err) {
...
}
```

the connect() is called when the Express server receives a request and the DB's URL is received from the request body.